# partial_fit with SGDClassifier gives fluctuating accuracy

Tags: python, scikit-learn, partial, logistic-regression, auc

I have my data in a sparse matrix. I work now first on a subset with ~500k rows before starting the big computation. The data is bigram counts plus entropy and string length, and the complete dataset contains 100s of millions of rows times 1400 columns. The model is meant to help characterise these strings, so I use `SGDClassifier` for logistic regression.

Because of the large size I decided to use `partial_fit` on my `SGDClassifier`, but the calculated `area-under-curve` value I get at each epoch seems to fluctuate a lot.

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
model = SGDClassifier(loss='log', alpha=1e-10, n_iter=50, n_jobs=-1, shuffle=True)
for f in file_list:
    data = dill.load(open(f))
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.2)
    X_train, X_holdout, y_train, y_holdout = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.05)
    for ep in range(max_epoch):
        model.partial_fit(X_train, y_train, classes=np.unique(y_train))

        # Calculate Area under ROC curve to see if things improve
        probs = model.predict_proba(X_holdout)
        auc   = roc_auc_score(y_holdout, [x[1] for x in probs])

        if auc > best_auc: best_auc = auc
        print('Epoch: %d - auc: %.2f (best %.2f)' %(ep, auc, best_auc))
```

What happens is that auc quickly goes up to ~0.9 but then fluctuates alot. Sometimes it drops to ~0.5-0.6 even and then back up. I thought that more logically `auc` should continue to generally increase with each epoch, with only small dips possible, until it finds a equilibrium value where more training hardly improve anything.

Is there anything I am doing wrong, or is this a possible "normal" behaviour with `partial_fit`? I never saw this behaviour when I used `fit` on the smaller dataset.

Comment: The above posted code seems wrong to me. You are splitting same data and labels twice (using the train_test_split), which will assign the X_train again with new data, but not the y_train which will contain values from 1st split. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: It was a mistype, I am writing the code on another computer than the one where the code is.

Comment: Ok. Why are you using `[x[1] for x in probs]` for y_pred in `roc_auc_score`? You can just use the `probs` in it.

Comment: Because probs has two columns one for each class, and when I try inputting simply `probe` I get a `ValueError: bad input shape ...`

Comment: Yes, but `x[1]` contains the probability of class1 (or whatever class is at that index), not the predicted class for that sample itself, hence your scores are affected by it. You should use the `prob`, or `model.predict(X_holdout)`.

Comment: But that will give me hard value predictions and results in that the ROC curve is not so "soft" instead. Is there any reason why it is wrong to instead predict probabilities of each class?

Comment: No, its not wrong. But are you sure, the x[1] is your positive class?

Comment: If you mean `positive class` == `1`, then yes it is x[1]. At least from manually checking predictions it seems to be the case. I don't know how else to check that easily.

Comment: Hey @Tobias did you get past this problem ? I am facing similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `partial_fit` has seen to be prone to [reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665417/mlp-with-partial-fit-performing-worse-than-with-fit-in-a-supervised-classifi) or [fluctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004926/partial-fit-with-sgdclassifier-gives-fluctuating-accuracy) in accuracy. To some extent, this can be slightly mitigated by shuffling and providing **only** small fractions of the entire dataset. But, for larger data, online training only seems to give reducing accuracies, with SGDClassifier/SVM Classifier.

I tried to experiment with it and discovered that using a low learning rate can help us sometimes. The rough analogy is, on training the same model on large data repeteadly, leads to the model forgetting what it learnt from the previous data. So, using a **tiny** learning rate slows down the rate of learning as well as forgetting!

Rather than manually providing a rate, we can use `adaptive` learning rate functionality provided by `sklearn`. Notice the model initialisation part,

```py
model = SGDClassifier(loss="hinge", penalty="l2", alpha=0.0001, max_iter=3000, tol=None, shuffle=True, verbose=0, learning_rate='adaptive', eta0=0.01, early_stopping=False)
```

This is described in the [scikit docs] as:

> ‘adaptive’: eta = eta0, as long as the training keeps decreasing. Each time n_iter_no_change consecutive epochs fail to decrease the training loss by tol or fail to increase validation score by tol if early_stopping is True, the current learning rate is divided by 5.

I got really good results (from initial drop from 98% to 28% in fourth part of the dataset) to 100% model accuracy with the change in learning rate.